# Cloud9 workspace using S3 bucket as source?

Tags: amazon-s3, ftp, sftp, cloud9-ide

Given the popularity of hosting static sites from AWS S3 buckets it would be great to be able to do that from Cloud9 too.

Is there any way I can set up an FTP-based workspace that uses an S3 bucket as the source?

Transmit and other FTP apps have the ability to work directly with an S3 bucket. I did try setting up an FTP workspace in Cloud9 using the following:

`Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Username: My-Access-Key
Password: My-Secret-Key`

I know it was a long-shot and I have since read confirmation that Amazon doesn't allow simple FTP access to buckets like that.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP workspaces on Cloud9 are actually being phased out, so I'd recommend using the mounting feature described in this blog post to mount an FTP source: https://c9.io/site/blog/2014/12/ftp-sftp-mounting-beta

Unfortunately, S3 doesn't support the FTP protocol, so this would have to be a new feature. Luckily we're opening up our SDK to be able to implement features like this. If you're interested in contributing please email us via https://support.c9.io

Answer (score 2):

Codeanywhere (https://codeanywhere.com) does this now. However, you'll have to shell out $7 to $10/m for that capability.

But then again, like Cloud9 (which I'm a big fan of), you get a bunch of features on the Codeanywhere IDE.

I was disappointed when Cloud9 discontinued its efforts on S/FTP. Codeanywhere seems to be taking on the cloud/storage issue head on by handling cloud access to S3, FTP, SFTP, Google Drive and others.

Comment: Finally, Amazon bought cloud9;)  
From its blog [Great News!](https://c9.io/blog/great-news/)